# Extract multi-value field in XML format in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I'm currently working with a database that stores XML record for all of its field, please see below example. Lets name the table CUSTOMER table.

```
customer table
     ------------------------------------------------------
     |  RECID | XMLRECORD                                 |
     |   1    | <row id='1' xml:space="preserve"><c1>...  |
     |   2    | <row id='2' xml:space="preserve"><c1>...  |
     |   3    | <row id='3' xml:space="preserve"><c1>...  |
     ------------------------------------------------------
```

All of the record of each customer is stored in 1 field called XMLRECORD, below is one example of XML RECORD of a customer.

```
<row id="1" xml:space="preserve">
  <c1>James</c1>
  <c2>Anderson</c2>
  <c3>25</c3>
  <c4>District 2 1657</c4>
  <c4 m="2">Riverside Drive Redding</c4>
  <c4 m="3">California, USA</c4>
</row>
```

Where **c1** would be the customer's first name, **c2** for last name, **c3** for age and **c4** would be the customer's address.

To query or extract values for each column, I usually use .value function to extract and return single value.

```
SELECT XMLRECORD.value('(/row/c4)[1]','NVARCHAR(20)') as ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Now my problem is this function only returns a single value, what I want is to return all the values under **c4**, which is multi value field. Can someone advise a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiating the table

```
declare @xml as table
(
    recid int,
    xmlrecord xml
)
insert into @xml
values

(   1    , '<row id="1" xml:space="preserve">
  <c1>James</c1>
  <c2>Anderson</c2>
  <c3>25</c3>
  <c4>District 2 1657</c4>
  <c4 m="2">Riverside Drive Redding</c4>
  <c4 m="3">California, USA</c4>
</row>' )

DECLARE @XMLRECORD as xml =
'<row id="1" xml:space="preserve">
  <c1>James</c1>
  <c2>Anderson</c2>
  <c3>25</c3>
  <c4>District 2 1657</c4>
  <c4 m="2">Riverside Drive Redding</c4>
  <c4 m="3">California, USA</c4>
</row>' ;
```

Using .nodes functionality to fetch all the nodes

```
SELECT  T.C.value('.','NVARCHAR(1000)') as c4_nodes FROM @XMLRECORD.nodes('(/row/c4)') as T(C)
```

Output -

```
c4_nodes
---------
District 2 1657
Riverside Drive Redding
California, USA
```

Since this fetches multiple records, using stuff command to concatenate the rows

```
SELECT
    recid
    ,STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + T.C.value('.','NVARCHAR(1000)')
    FROM XMLRECORD.nodes('(/row/c4)') as T(C)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') c4

    FROM @xml
```

Output -

```
recid | c4
-----------
1   District 2 1657,Riverside Drive Redding,California, USA
```

Answer (score 0):

**c4** should not repeat multiple time. data should be stored in single node. For all node value, you should use [*] to get all node value.

Comment: for the c4 in the XML, this is how our system stores value in the XML. Are you suggesting to replace [1] to [*]?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT Tmp.record.value('.','NVARCHAR(20)')  
FROM   [customer] 
CROSS APPLY [XMLRECORD].nodes('/row/c4') as Tmp(record)
```